# Do we need to copy the flurry dll folder into the windows phone project while integrating?

Tags: windows-phone-7, flurry

I was trying to integrate flurry analytics to my Windows Phone 7.5 app. I have downloaded the SDK. Im confused as to where to put the folder inside my project? Do I have to copy the whole dll folder and put it inside my project folder? Or can I reference it from anywhere? My project is monitored by Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import the SDK with Git? If so, in your solution explorer, click references. You should see the flurry analytics reference there. Check the properties to copy it to your output folder. 
For developing purposes it really doesn't matter when it's located, i prefer to place it in a folder inside my trunk folder for backup purposes.